# app unforunatly stopped on data parsing on intent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-intent

I am getting a run time error "RemindMe is unfortunately stopped" on AddReminder activity  when I passed a username from logging activity to Menu then attempt to add reminder activity, it unfortunately stops. Also logcat is not showing me anything (its empty).

Loging.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.champ.remindme2.Login"
android:background="@drawable/back">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/remind_me_logo"
    android:contentDescription="Logo" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtitem"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/username_rounded_edited_text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/pass_rounded_edited_text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtitem"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_botton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:onClick="Login"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/password" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/txtSignup"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_botton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Signup"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:onClick="Signup"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LoginButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LoginButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LoginButton" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/fb_loging"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSignup"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtSignup"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtSignup" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Loging.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText ed1Username, ed2Pass;
String Username;
int counter=3;
Button LoginButton;
// TextView txtAttempts;
//private final int interval = 3000;
/*private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        LoginButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}; */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    LoginButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);
    ed1Username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtitem);
    Username=ed1Username.getText().toString();
    ed2Pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
}


public void Login(View v){

    if (ed1Username.getText().toString().equals("Admin") && ed2Pass.getText().toString().equals("123")){
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        intent.putExtra("Username",Username);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        counter--;
    }
   // txtAttempts.setText("Attempts Left: " + counter);

    if (counter == 0) {
        LoginButton.setEnabled(false);
  //      new Timer().schedule((TimerTask) runnable,interval);
    }
}

public void Signup(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, signup.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Menu.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/back"
tools:context="com.example.champ.remindme2.Menu">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:src="@drawable/remind_me_logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Reminder"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="addReminder"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View List"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Shop"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View profile"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu.java

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
}

public void addReminder(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddReminder.class);
    String Username = intent.getExtras().getString("Username");
    intent.putExtra("Username", Username);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

AddReminder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.champ.remindme2.AddReminder"
android:background="@drawable/back">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:src="@drawable/remind_me_logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtitem"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edited_text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/plusButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6"
    android:text="Add Item"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/plusButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/plusButton"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_botton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:onClick="plus"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NextButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NextButton" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/NextButton"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_botton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:onClick="AddEventPlace"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BackButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView6" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BackButton"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_botton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:onClick="Back"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtitem"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtitem" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

AddReminder.java

```
public class AddReminder extends AppCompatActivity {
String item;
//Passing Value Through String
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_reminder);
    EditText edtItem= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtitem);
    item=edtItem.getText().toString();
}

public void AddEventPlace(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddEventPlace.class);
    String Username = intent.getExtras().getString("Username");
    intent.putExtra("Username", Username);
    intent.putExtra("item",item);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: **Problem is:** Get text from `EditText ` on Button click event which provide you text input by user. currently you are calling getText method of EditText in `onCreate` which probably return empty or null string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my updated code, Hope it will help...

1) Updated Menu Activity -

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    username = getIntent().getStringExtras("Username");
}

public void addReminder(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddReminder.class);
    intent.putExtra("Username", username);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

2) Updated AddReminder Activity -

```
public class AddReminder extends AppCompatActivity {
String item;
String username;
//Passing Value Through String
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_reminder);
    EditText edtItem= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtitem);
    item=edtItem.getText().toString();
    username = getIntent().getStringExtras("Username");
}

public void AddEventPlace(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddEventPlace.class);
    intent.putExtra("Username", username);
    intent.putExtra("item",item);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: its getStringExtra() not getStringExtras(). any how thanks its worked. @Onkar Nene